# React Native Expo app won't open on other devices after 'expo publish'

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

After running `expo publish` as instructed by the expo docs, the app opens and everything is fine on my device.

On other devices, however, the app will not open. It simply says 'Something went wrong'. I have had others try to open on **ios** and **android**, and it seems to be a problem on all devices other than my own. I've tried having other people login with my credentials and that produced the same result. I made the app public, so I do not think that is the issue?

Has anyone else experienced this problem or something similar? I tried republishing a couple times but that didn't do anything. I have been making the project on Ubuntu 16.04, fyi.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you tried checking what Logcat or the ios console print out when using a connected physical device?

Comment: I have not checked that but on the expo app it says the following: For Android it says **'Uncaught Error: Error while updating property 'width' in shadow node of type: RCTText'**, and on IOS it says **The experience you requested is not viewable by you. You will need to log in or ask the owner to grant you access.'** So potenitally two issues, it seems?

Comment: Seems likely. I would go ahead and debug the applications on a real device (not an emulator) using Android Studio/Xcode respectively and see what you get. The first issue you mentioned seems to be related to UI.